# akka ignite persistence failed with NullPointerException

Tags: akka, persistence, ignite

AKKA persistence support various DB and cache DB's. We are planning to use AKKA persistence with Ignite INMEMORY DB. But unfortunately we have followed all the configuration and attribute changes. But still we are not able to integrate AKKA persistence with Ignite DB. It shows NullPointerException and we are not able to create Journal and Snapshot for the same.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at akka.japi.Util$.option(JavaAPI.scala:271) ~[93:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
        at akka.persistence.snapshot.japi.SnapshotStore.$anonfun$loadAsync$1(SnapshotStore.scala:20) ~[96:com.typesafe.akka.persistence:2.5.11]
        at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:251) ~[415:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.7.v20180926-092622-VFINAL-d96b8eb]
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209) ~[415:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.7.v20180926-092622-VFINAL-d96b8eb]
       at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:288) ~[415:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.7.v20180926-092622-VFINAL-d96b8eb]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29) ~[415:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.7.v20180926-092622-VFINAL-d96b8eb]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29) ~[415:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.7.v20180926-092622-VFINAL-d96b8eb]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60) ~[415:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.7.v20180926-092622-VFINAL-d96b8eb]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55) ~[93:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) ~[93:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12) [415:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.7.v20180926-092622-VFINAL-d96b8eb]
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81) [415:org.scala-lang.scala-library:2.12.7.v20180926-092622-VFINAL-d96b8eb]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91) [93:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [93:com.typesafe.akka.actor:2.5.11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?]
```

Comment: I would suggest sending this question to Ignite developer community as long as you’re trying to integrate with another library/framework.

Comment: I also think you need to specify a bit more about what you mean by "all the configuration and attribute changes", especially given that there is no out of the box plug-in for ignite. I'm also a bit confused as to why you'd want to do that, since you are essentially sharding the data in-memory twice (once in Akka, once in Ignite).